# Retirement Plan Income - Distribution Amount

Tags: united-states, taxes, ira, form-1099

Last year I didn't have 401k and IRA plan. The reason was I moved to a new company. The company's policy is *not* to provide any retirement benefit in the first year. I wanted to buy $4000 by myself for making up year 2013 IRA to reduce my tax. Today I am working on the tax form, hopefully complete it via software before April 15.

Here is the question, I don't have the form 1099-R at hand. The payer said that they would mail me the document in the next half year. But I need to fill the entries in the tax software. Not sure how?

```
1. Gross distribution:    
2a. Taxable amount: 
2b. Taxable amount not determined:
2b. Total distribution: 
3. Capital gains (included in box 2a): 
4. Federal income tax withheld: 
5. Contributions or insurance premiums:  Learn More
6. Unrealized appreciation in employer securities
```

**UPDATE:**
I am not sure what kind of form needed. I just want to fill these headache numbers. From the broker's web site. I got the information below.

```
Will I receive a 1099-R or 1099-Q?


If you had a reportable distribution in 2011 from your IRA or Coverdell ESA, 
the form is mailed from our office no later than January 31. We will mail you
a 1099-R if you had a reportable distribution from your IRA, and a 1099-Q   
you had a reportable distribution from your Coverdell ESA.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be mailed a 1099-R if you had *received* a distribution (taken money out or rolled it over into a new plan) from your 401K or IRA account.

Depending on whether your employer had a retirement plan available, and subject to income and filing status limitations, your entry for IRA deduction would end up on line 32 of your 1040.

There should be a separate field for entering your IRA contribution into the tax software.  Your broker (or otherwise) should have a record of exactly how much you have contributed.

You can make contributions up to April 15th of 2014, and have them count towards your 2013 contributions, as long as they are below the limit and are designated for 2013 when you make them.

Comment: @jonscae, I updated the statement.

Comment: @Love The same rules apply.  In that case, there would be no limitations on contributions that would have been in place due to having a plan available to you.

Comment: @Jonscae, because April 15th is approaching. If the broker mails the form after the deadline, how can I handle it?

Comment: @Love You won't be receiving any IRS form for your contributions.  Your broker will likely send you a statement of how much you have contributed for your own records.

Comment: @Love Does that edit clarify it?

Comment: Thanks, @jonsca. So in normal case, I don't need to fill these numbers? I just used the money buying a fund yesterday. No distribution at all.

Comment: @Love You will fill those fields in when you take money out or do a rollover

Comment: @jonsca: "In that case, there would be no limitations on contributions that would have been in place due to having a plan available to you" Well, he didn't say what he did *before* he "moved to a new company". It's possible that he was covered by an employer retirement plan for part of the year.

Comment: @user102008 That's very true.  For the basis of that comment, I'm going by the opening sentence of the OP and assuming that he/she meant for the entire year.  It doesn't change the fundamental answer to the question either way, and I left the caveat of "depending on whether your employer had a plan available" in the answer.